# Line and area plot on the same axis, and a common legend

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I would like to plot one column from a DataFrame as an area, and another one as a line on the right Y axis, and then have both these entries in a common legend. Here is a small example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame({'a': [1,3,2], 'b': [4,5,2]})
df.a.plot(kind='area', label='A', legend=True)
df.b.plot(kind='line', secondary_y=True, style='r', label='B', legend=True)
```

[image: image produced by code above]

The legend has only the second label (B), but not A. Also, in the legend A should be a patch (rectangle), and B - a line. What is the best way to do this in pandas & matplotlib?

Thank you,

Aleksey